# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'flexigrid'

Tags: flexigrid

guys! I was trying to add flexigrid plugin into my html, but i have problem that

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'flexigrid' showed
>   in chrome console

my code is

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<script src="/houtai_xiangmu/js/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/houtai_xiangmu/js/flexigrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/houtai_xiangmu/js/flexigrid.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/houtai_xiangmu/js/jquery-1.2.3.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    alert("123");
    $("#flex1").flexigrid
            (
            {
            url: 'post2.php',
            dataType: 'json',
```

I tried add alert in flexigrid.js file, it works!